# jQuery / Ajax: How to loop through array as part of Ajax success function

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, loops

I have an **Ajax call** that returns an array and need to do something with each of the values from this array.

**So far I have the below but this returns the following error:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in array(5)...
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here resp. how I can do something with each of the values ?

**My Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "post",   
    url: "ajax.php",
    cache: "false",
    data: {
        node: 'fetchValues',
        itemIDs: itemIDs
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);  // for testing only
        jQuery.each(data, function(index, value){
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
});
```

**Example for "data"** (from console log)**:**

```
array(5) {
  [1]=>
  string(6) "Value1"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "Value2"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "Value3"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "Value4"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "Value5"
}
```

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried a simple for?
var x=0;
for(x;x<data.length;x++) {  var value=data[x]; }

Comment: try this one for(var x in data){ console.log(x + ' :' + data[x]);

Comment: @RicardoPontual: Yes, I tried this before but it returns an error referring to the length.

Comment: @HadiHassan: Thanks for this. Wouldn't I need to use this with a loop ?

Comment: @TaneMahuta I didn't get what you mean, but the comment i provided above will loop to each property in the returned object via ajax

Comment: @HadiHassan: Thanks. This returns / logs every single characters separately !

Comment: @TaneMahuta then i recommend you to parse json your data as mentioned in the answer below

Comment: @TaneMahuta have you fixed the issue? Whats the issue?

Answer (score 5):

seems like your array not parsed properly

from php side before sending response

```
echo json_encode($result); // REPLACE $result WITH  YOUR OUTPUT ARRAY
```

On jquery side:

```
$.ajax({        
    type: "post",   
    url: "ajax.php",
    dataType : 'JSON',
    cache: "false",
    data: {
        node: 'fetchValues',
        itemIDs: itemIDs
    },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);  // for testing only
       var data=$.parseJSON(data);
        jQuery.each(data, function(index, value){
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
});
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: Thanks for this. I had tried something similar before but this returns the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a... "

Comment: @TaneMahuta before sending response are use using json_encode() ? Whats your server side script? Is it PHP?

Comment: Not here. Should I try that ?

Comment: Whats your server side script? Is it PHP?

Comment: Yes - currently I am just dumping the array there.

Comment: @TaneMahuta after `dataType : 'JSON',` I missed a comma (,) try updated one

Comment: Thanks ! I tried but this returns nothing, neither with echo nor with var_dump.

Comment: @TaneMahuta have you replaced $result with your variable before encoding it? check whether you are getting data in json format?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83740/discussion-between-version-beta-and-tanemahuta).

Comment: @TaneMahuta you received the response in json format? have you added `dataType : 'JSON',` also before sending request to ajax? have you refreshed your page?

Comment: @TaneMahuta can you post `console.log(data);` result?

Comment: Thanks for your updates and sorry for the delay - I had to go offline for a while. I have tried this but then console logs nothing, not even an error. Would you still be available for a chat ?

Comment: Thanks - I am opening the chat now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the string in your `data` variable to an object:

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data);  // for testing only
    var res=$.parseJSON(data);
    jQuery.each(res, function(index, value){
        console.log(value);
    });
}
```

You can either use

```
var res=$.parseJSON(data)
```

Or plain JS:

```
var res=JSON.parse(data)
```

**[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23673229/2065039)**

Comment: Thanks for this. I had tried something similar before but this returns the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token a... " - same as for the answer above.

Comment: Try giving `$(data)` in `$.each` instead of plaint `data`

Comment: Thanks - you mean to change this in your parseJSON line and to use $.each instead of jQuery.each ?

Comment: Thanks - there is no data in your jQuery.each. :)

Comment: ok. just `console.log(res)` and `console.log($(res));` using my method and let me know what you are getting?